# How to define dynamic interface/struct

Tags: go, struct, interface, channel

I'm pretty new to Go and really looking for some guidance.

In my application I have a channel that receives events, I'd like to have an interface like:

```
{
  "type": "event1",
  "data": {}
}
```

where the structure of `data` depends on the `type`.

Then the code that listen for those events in the channel will know what kind of structure to expect based on the type of the event.

How can I define such interface?
Is that considered a good practice in Go?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `type switch`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type X struct {
    i int
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan interface{}, 5)
    c <- 4
    c <- "hi"
    c <- X{}
    close(c)

    for value := range c {
        switch v := value.(type) {
        case int:
            fmt.Println("got int", v)
        case string:
            fmt.Println("got string", v)
        case X:
            fmt.Println("got X", v)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("unexpected type %T\n", value)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just a normal `switch` since they already have a `string` field that gives a type indicator.

Comment: That's true, if `event` always corresponds to the type of data, then that would be a simpler solution.